# Are electric kettles a good choice for tea?

Tags: tea

From my experience, electric kettles stop only when the water is at a rolling boil, which is bad because:

1. The water loses oxygen when at a rolling boil
2. If you make teas other than black or herbals (like white, oolong or green) you may bruise the leaves with boiling water

So are electric kettles recommended for tea making?

Comment: You've already answered your own question. You've clearly stated you do not want the loss of dissolved oxygen, or possibly bruising the leaves from a rolling boil.
The answer for your conditions is clearly , NO they are not.
I drink orange pekoe and black teas and electric kettles are perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 7):

Well, my kettle will boil water to 70, 80, 90 or 100 degrees, which eliminates all of those problems you mention. If you are concerned about those things I would recommend shopping around for a kettle with more functionality.